# SQL given multiple thresholds, get largest value below each threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am given multiple thresholds (usually 2, but may vary). I would like to find, for each threshold, the row with the largest value lesser than or equal to the threshold in each category.

e.g. Given category 2 and thresholds 5 and 10:

```
mytable:
category | val | data
---------+-----+---------
1        | 1   | 'foo'
1        | 3   | 'bar'
1        | 4   | 'baz'
2        | 2   | 'quz'
2        | 5   | 'wibble'
2        | 6   | 'wobble'
2        | 8   | 'ham'
2        | 12  | 'spam'
3        | 1   | 'eggs'
```

So the result should be:

```
category | val | data
---------+-----+---------
1        | 4   | 'baz'     \
2        | 5   | 'wibble'  | These are <= threshold 5
3        | 1   | 'eggs'    /
1        | 4   | 'baz'     \
2        | 8   | 'ham'     | These are <= threshold 10
3        | 1   | 'eggs'    /
```

NOTE: It is also ok if the rows are distinct, but not necessary.

So far, I'm only able to come with with a query for 1 threshold (basically, a standard greatest-n-per-group query):

```
SELECT t1.category, t1.val, t1.data
FROM mytable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT category, MAX(val) AS val
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY category
  WHERE val < @threshold
) AS t2
ON t1.category=t2.category AND t1.val=t2.val
```

How do I deal with multiple thresholds?

If it matters, I am on T-SQL. A general SQL query would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply specify the thresholds as rows so that it is easier to join.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (category int, val int, data varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 1, 'foo'),
(1, 3, 'bar'),
(1, 4, 'baz'),
(2, 2, 'quz'),
(2, 5, 'wibble'),
(2, 6, 'wobble'),
(2, 8, 'ham'),
(2, 12, 'spam'),
(3, 1, 'eggs');

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY threshold, category ORDER BY val DESC) AS rn
    FROM (VALUES
        (5),
        (10)
    ) thresholds(threshold)
    JOIN @t AS t ON val <= threshold
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY threshold, category
```

If `(VAULES ...)` clause is unavailable you can simply use `FROM (SELECT 5 AS threshold UNION ALL SELECT 10) thresholds`.